# How to exit the loop with the number 0? but now i have other problems

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
package hw3;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NumberOfElements = 1000;
        int[] num = new int[NumberOfElements];
        int var = 0;
        //create input
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfElements; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter any positive number or enter 0 to stop: ");
            num[i] = input.nextInt();
            var++; 
            if (num[i] == 0)

                break;

            }
             Arrays.sort( num, 0, var);
             int i;
             for (i = 0; i < var; i++) {
             System.out.print("   " + num[i]);


        }
    }
}
```

Write a Java program reading a sequence of positive integers entered one per line. The program stops reading when integer ‘0’ is entered. The program will sort and output them into an ascending numerical order.For example: 5
                     1
                     7
              12
                     36
                     8
                     0
Output: 1 5 7 8 12 36

Comment: What JDK are you using? With OpenJDK 1.6.0 I see no extra zero in the output.

Comment: okay it seems to work now..after i copied and pasted..

Comment: Do you Really need to use arrays? is that specified in the assignment?

Comment: i think so because we briefly learned it

Comment: Is there also a way of doing it by swapping numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to understand the problem: there are three steps.
Step 1: Get the input from the user. Continue getting input till the user enters 0
Step 2: Sort
Step 3: Print out the results

**Step 1:** Your `for` loop is almost correct.
But the for loop should end immediately after you have got the input.
In the following code,

```
   num[i] = input.nextInt();
   var++; 
   if (num[i] == 0)
      break;
```

you are adding the user input to the array and then checking whether it is `0`. This means that the `0` will also be part of your array. If you don't want this, you should check the input and add it to the array only if it is not `0`.

Also note the declaration of `i` before the `for` loop. Because we need it after the for loop. Why? see below.

```
int i = 0; 
for (i = 0; i < NumberOfElements; i++) {
   int n = input.nextInt();
    if (n == 0)
       break;
    else
       num[i] = n;
} //for loop ends here
```

**Step 2:** Sort it
`Arrays.sort(num);`

**Step 3:** Print the output:

```
for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
      System.out.print("  " + num[i]);
   }
```

The problem is, in step 2, an array of 1000 elements is sorted, while you actually need to consider only the number of elements the user has entered. You don't know that initially thats why you created an array of 1000 elements.But, at this point (after step 2) you *do* know how many number of elements the user has entered. This is present in `i`

So new step between 1 and 2: Create a new arrays that contains only those elements that the user has entered.
**Step 1.5:**

```
int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(num, i);
```

Now sort this new array, and print it (same as your code, but uses the new array we just created)

`Arrays.sort(newArray);`

```
for (i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
      System.out.print("  " + newArray[i]);
   }
```

**Notes:**
1. The ideal way to do this is to use Lists and not arrays, but probably since this is homework, you might *have* to use arrays.

1. Since this is homework, I don't know whether you are allowed to use `Arrays.sort` or `Arrays.copy`. Your professor might frown at this because perhaps his intention was that you learn the constructs of the language via `for`, `if` and `while`. In that case you have to do step 1.5 (make array the right size) and sort by yourself.
   This is not difficult (but just remember this is not the best way to do it, except for in a homework)

***Copy array (homemade) (in place of step 1.4 above)***

```
int[] newArray = new int[i]
for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
   newArray[j] = num[j];
}
```

***Sort (homemade) (in place of step 2 above):***

1. Loop through the elements
2. If one element is greater than the previous element, *swap* them (in asc order, the prev element is always lesser or equal to the next element)

There are two loops because you have to do the comparison on a continuous basis: the the first element, compare with the entire array, place it in the right position, take the second compare with the entire array etc...)

```
  for(int j=0; j<newArray.length; j++) {
      for(int k=0; k<newArray.length; k++) {
         if(newArray[k] > newArray[j]) { 
            //the swap logic:
            int t = newArray[k];
            newArray[k] = newArray[j];
            newArray[j] = t;
         }
      }
   }
```

Try to understand what really is happening, instead of just copy pasting.
Once you understand the homemade sort logic, think about this:
The second for loop in the sort `or(int k=0; k<newArray.length; k++) {` can actually just be  `for(int k=0; k<newArray.length; k++) {`. Why?

Your print loop will remain the way you wrote it, but you will print `newArray` rather than `num`. You might want to change the loop variable to `int j` or something, but `i` will also work. (`i` holds the no of inputs now, so I would not use it for any other purpose. But it is just a manner of coding. Technically no difference - the code will work the same way)

I am not combining the parts. I leave that o you, otherwise it will look like I did your homework :-)

Comment: Wow Thank you I didn't even look at the bottom of the page till now. Thanks!!

Comment: "If you don't want this, you should check the input and add it to the array only if it is not 0. "
how do I do that is it something like !=0...?

Comment: you can accept the answer if it works for you :-)  (In SO, when you get an answer for your question, and you are satisfied with it, you "Accept" it by clicking the tick mark near the answer. See the ***"How do I ask questions here?"*** section in http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: I have added an example, see the code in the first for loop: `if (n == 0) break; else num[i] = n;`

Comment: if (num[i] != 0)
          continue;
          else break;
still includes the zero

Comment: :-) but make sure this is what you need before you accept it. Take your time.

Comment: No not `if (num[i] != 0)`. You should get it in a temporary variable first, check if it is `0` and add to array only if it is not. See the for loop in my answer (just before step 2) completely

Comment: i dont think i am suppose to include the zero....do I have to drastically change the code for it to work ?  oh yeah i should probably mention that he said we should be able to do it with 2 for and 1 if statement

Comment: @CuriousStudent, perhaps you did not understand what I said. The code I have given already **does not include** the zero. Try reading the answer completely, and understanding the code I have given. The code to ignore the zeros is in the first for loop of my answer

Comment: Oh I understand it works! okay Now on to problem 2 of my homework lol.  It's due in 6 hours I guess i'm not sleeping tonight considering its 2:24am already.

Answer (score 0):

Here your application is reading int, you can check that the last one is != from 0. And `break` the loop.
If you don't like using break, you can still add a condition to your `for`.

For sorting an array, there is the `Arrays.sort()` solution.

And to print them you'll need another loop, but beware as you can have less than 1000 items in your array you can't simply print the whole array.
You'll need to find a way to count the number of elements you added in the array.

---

After your edit:

Good your application seems to work here is what I got :

> Mac-Makkhdyn:~ Makkhdyn$ java hw3.Main
>   Enter any positive number or enter 0 to stop: 1
>   Enter any positive number or enter 0 to stop: 2
>   Enter any positive number or enter 0 to stop: 3
>   Enter any positive number or enter 0 to stop: 4
>   Enter any positive number or enter 0 to stop: 5
>   Enter any positive number or enter 0 to stop: 0
>   Mac-Makkhdyn:~ Makkhdyn$

The 0 you have must be from somewhere else. Isn't your actual code slightly different from the one you posted here ?

---

**Resources :**

- [javadoc - Arrays.sort()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5b%5d%29)
- [Java tutorial - The `break` Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Comment: System.out.print("Accending order number : ");
    Arrays.sort(num);
    for(i = 0;i < num.length;i++){
      System.out.print("  " + num[i]);
            }

Comment: As I said, you can't print the whole array, because there is a (huge) possibility that it isn't entirely filled.

Comment: hm...so i have to somehow change the array to the number of times the user inputted a number?

Comment: Or as I said above, you could count the number of elements you put in your array.

Comment: @CuriousStudent, you'll need to "remember" how many numbers were entered. :)

Comment: sorry reason why I can't do that is because I do not know how. Is there a link you can point me to?  My prof didn't teach it to us he just gave us the assignment and told us to figure it out somehow.

Comment: @st0le this program is for an user to input the data so I can't predict how many numbers he/she is going to enter

Comment: i mean i can do something like this System.out.print ("How many digits are you going to enter? ");
        int x = input.nextInt();
        int[] num = new int [x]; but i do not think that is the most efficient way.

Comment: You can declare your own int as a counter, and increment it by one each time you get an answer.

Comment: Another thing, you should really get your "sorting and printing" part out of the for loop.

Comment: am i on the right track? 
 int answers;
        for (answers = 0; answers == i; answers++){
          System.out.print ("the number of answers entered is " +answers);

Comment: @CuriousStudent, i actually meant to store the value of `i` in another variable when you break out of the loop. Colin's Suggestion works too :)

Comment: @st0le I dont know how; i'm basically trying to do this assignment by reading the book and online :(  ....we only had 3 lectures so far

Comment: @CuriousStudent, you don't need to. But since you're a beginner, i'd suggest you do it as simple as possible, make another variable `count` initialize it with the size of the array. now, in the loop, before the `break` statement, add `count = i`...finally, display all values of array between `0..count` :) hope it helps

Comment: @CuriousStudent, Did you learn about how you can declare variables ? In this case you can create a new one, before the loop. And you add 1 to this variable (`var = var+1`) each time you add a number to your array. This way you know how many elements there is.

Comment: @CuriousStudent, i spotted a problem, that'll occur...since your Array is of size `1000`, its initialised to `0`...Now, `Arrays.sort()` will sort the `entire` array. (ie all 1000 elements) even though the user might have entered just 10 values...the array will end up with a bunch of 0's in the front.

Comment: yeah lol 0 0 0 0 0 3 2 1...i get something like that. okay i'll try both ways @colin @st0le

Comment: okay cool the counting is working now; to the next issue lol the sorting

Comment: @CuriousStudent, use `Arrays.sort( arr[], from, to)` :)

Comment: LOL I dont know how to use it like that.  Arrays.sort( arr[], [0], [var]);  ??

http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/array.shtml  
doesn't teach that haha.

Comment: in the book I see you can do swapping but boy is that complicated

Comment: @st0le, why "from", "to" ? Just Arrays.sort(array) is enough. You only have to get the n last elements later.

Comment: @colin but when i do that it only prints out zeros

Comment: When you do your loop for printing elements. Instead of starting from 0, start from the `array.length - number of addedElements` and go to the end of the array ;)

Comment: run:
Enter any positive number or enter 0 to stop: 7
Enter any positive number or enter 0 to stop: 4
Enter any positive number or enter 0 to stop: 2
Enter any positive number or enter 0 to stop: 0
   0           2           4           7        BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)
How do I take out that zero?

Comment: In the example that the prof gave us he didn't have the zero in the output :(

Comment: @Colin, not really...what if the input contains negative values? edit: i just realized, op's states it's all positive....cool, then it'll work!! :)

Answer (score 0):

`num[i]` holds the last number you are reading. So you have to compare it against `0` and if it is `0`, you have to end the loop. Read about [**branching statements**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) to find out how to do that.

It is probably also good for you to read about [**control flow statements**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html) in general.

Comment: weird now i copy paste it and it seems to work...okay i guess now its on to the next problem which is adding the arrays.sort() without printing out 1000 characters....